# Octal, Decimal, or Hexadecimal?

Tags: code-golf, base-conversion

Given an input string containing only letters and numbers, write a program or function that prints the possible printable ASCII characters (Hex 20-7E) that correspond with the string's value in bases 8, 10, and 16 (where possible). The characters must be written in increasing order in terms of the bases with which they correspond (base 8 first, etc). The output can be in array format (like `[& . F]`) or separated by spaces or newlines (a trailing newline is optional) like the samples.

If there is not a possible printable ASCII character that can be formed, the program must not have any output.

**Samples**

```
31
==> 1

47
==> ' / G

69
==> E i

7A
==> z

100
==> @ d

156
==> n

189
==> <empty>

potaTO
==> <empty>

5G
==> <empty>

19
==> <empty>
```

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the answer with the fewest bytes wins. Standard rules apply.

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (SpiderMonkey 30+), 74 bytes

```
s=>[for(b of'o0x')if((c=+(0+b+s))>31&c<127)String.fromCharCode(c)].join` `
```

Comment: You and your ES7 are killing mah ES6 o_o

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ When you're using both `map` and `filter`, array comprehensions are really useful.

Comment: @Neil Any reason to use `'0'+b+...` when `b` will always be a string? `0+b+...`

Comment: @dev-null Bah, I fixed it in http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/73323/17602 but forgot to do it here too.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 23 <s>24</s> <s>28</s> bytes

*1 byte off thanks to @David*

```
8H6hhYs"G@ZA32:126m?6Mc
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OEg2aGhZcyJHQFpBMzI6MTI2bT82TWM&input=JzQ3Jw)

```
8H6hhYs         % array [8,10,16]
"               % for each base
  G             %   push input. Do nothing the first time
  @             %   push base (8, 10 or 16)
  ZA            %   convert from base to decimal. Takes implicit input the first time
  32:126m       %   is result in acceptable range?
  ?             %   if so
    6M          %     push result of base conversion again
    c           %     convert to char
                %   implicitly end if
                % implicitly end for each
                % implicitly display stack contents
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the  `D` is necessary, is it? Nice work on creating the vector, I did almost the same as you but couldn't shorten the vector from `[8,10,16]`.

Comment: @David Thanks! I thought `D` was necessary in this case to empty the stack. But you're right, it's not! Thanks!

Comment: @David I need to include `' ':'~'` as a predefined literal for next release!

Comment: `32:126m` is a good idea!!

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, <s>84</s> 82 bytes

```
def a(s):
 for n in 8,10,16:
  try:b=int(s,n);31<b<127and print(chr(b))
  except:0
```

Answer (score 3):

### Pyth, <s>23</s> <s>21</s> <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```
@rd\m.xCizd0[8T16
```

Output as an array. There's a literal `\x80` between the backslash and the C, which I've replaced with a `•`.

```
@rd\•m.xCizd0[8T16    Implicit: z=input
     m     d [8T16    Map the following lambda d over [8, 10, 16]:
      .x                try:
         izd              convert z from that base
        C                                          and convert to char
            0           except: return the number 0
@                     Filter that on presence in
 rd\•                   strings from space to \x80 (the printable ASCII characters).
```

Try it [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40rd%5C%C2%80m.xCizd0%5B8T16&input=100&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=31%0A47%0A69%0A7A%0ApotaTO&debug=1).

Answer (score 2):

## Jolf, 26 bytes

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=IGbOnOKAmENpOGnOl2nigJlkcEFIZGggc0giWyAtfl0) [Test suite](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=IGbOnOKAmENpOGnOl2nigJlkcEFIZGggc0giWyAtfl0&input=MzEKCjQ3Cgo2OQoKN0EKCjEwMAoKMTU2CgoxODkKCnBvdGFUTwoKNUcKCjE5)

```
 fΜ‘Ci8iΗi’dpAHdh sH"[ -~]
```

## Explanation

```
 fΜ‘Ci8iΗi’dpAHdh sH"[ -~]
   ‘      ’                array containing
    Ci8                     input as base 8
       i                    input as base 10
        Ηi                  input as base 16
  Μ        d               mapped
            pAH             with from char code
_f             d           filtered
                _sH"[ -~]   with strings matching that.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Bash + GNU utilities + [ascii](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/ascii/ascii.html), 36

Not sure if the use of the `ascii` utility is allowed.  Input is taken as a commandline parameter.

```
ascii $1|tac|grep -Po '(?<=s as `).'
```

`ascii` may be installed on Ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install ascii`.

Answer (score 1):

## C (function), 76

- 2 bytes saved thanks to @anatolyg.
- 5 bytes saved thanks to @luserdroog.

```c
j,c;f(char*s){for(j=8;c=strtol(s,0,j);j=j*j/6)isprint(c)?printf("%c ",c):0;}
```

[Ideone.](https://ideone.com/bqkcOW)

Comment: Your loop "increment" statement is awesome! It could be shortened though.

Comment: `j*=j,j/=6` is more plainly written as `j=j*j/6`

Comment: @anatolyg of course  -thanks!  I was trying to be clever with combining operators  - something like `j*=j/6` but that didn't work due to loss of precision during integer division

Comment: `j<20,` the comma operator discards the whole effect of this.

Comment: @luserdroog Yes - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript ES6, 89 chars

```
s=>'0o,,0x'.split`,`.map(x=>(x+=s)>31&x<128&&String.fromCharCode(x)).filter(x=>x).join` `
```

Test:

```
f=s=>'0o,,0x'.split`,`.map(x=>(x+=s)>31&x<128&&String.fromCharCode(x)).filter(x=>x).join` `
"31,47,69,7A,100,156,189,potaTo,5G,19".split`,`.map(f) == "1,' / G,E i,z,@ d,n,,,,"
```

Answer (score 1):

### Lua, 147 Bytes

I don't think I can golf it down a lot more, I've tested a lot of ways to do it, and here come the shortest. Even using an old compiler which contains the deprecated function `table.foreach(table,function)` doesn't shave off some bytes.

This program takes a string as argument, and print the concatenation of a table values separated by spaces.

```lua
t={}for _,i in pairs({8,10,16})do x=tonumber(arg[1],i)x=x and x or 0 t[#t+1]=127>x and 19<x and string.char(x)or nil end print(table.concat(t," "))
```

#### Ungolfed and explanations

```lua
t={}                        -- Initalise the array containing the chars to print
for _,i in pairs({8,10,16}) -- Iterate over the array {8,10,16}
do
  x=tonumber(arg[1],i)      -- convert the input in base i to a number in base 10
  x=x and x or 0            -- if the input wasn't a number, x is nil
                            -- use a ternary operator to set x in this case
  t[#t+1]=127>x and 19<x    -- if x is the bytecode of a printable character
    and string.char(x)or nil-- insert this character into t
end
print(table.concat(t," "))  -- concatenate the values in t with " " as separator
                            -- and print it
```

If you're wandering why there's a variable set but not used in a golfed code (the variable `_` in the for loop), here's why:

You have 2 ways to iterate over an array in Lua, either in a for style:

```lua
for i=1,#table do --[[code here, use table[i] ]] end
```

or in a foreach style:

```lua
for key,value do pairs(table) do --[[code here]] end
```

I was needing the values contained in the table `{8,10,16}` as they are the different bases I have to iterate over. But functions with multiple return won't allow you to chose which one you actually want to be returned, they follow an order. To have the variable `value` set, I need to catch the value of `key` too: that's what we call a dummy `_`.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>89</s> 88 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to Neil!

```
n=>[..."0x+"].map(t=>String.fromCharCode(eval(`0${t+n}`))).filter(k=>~k.search(/[ -~]/))
```

Returns an array. If that's not okay, this works for an extra 8 bytes, displaying the possible matches.

```
n=>[..."0x+"].map(t=>String.fromCharCode(eval(`0${t+n}`))).filter(k=>~k.search(/[ -~]/)).join` `
```

```js
F=n=>[..."0x+"].map(t=>String.fromCharCode(eval(`0${t+n}`))).filter(k=>~k.search(/[ -~]/)).join` `
//`
U=x=>o.innerHTML=F(+i.value);
i.onchange=i.onkeydown=i.onkeyup=i.onkeypress=U;U();
```

```css
*{font-family:Consolas,monospace;}
```

```html
<input id=i type="number" value=31><div id=o></div>
```

Comment: Hmm, how old a JavaScript do you need that numbers beginning with 0 parse as octal?

Comment: @Neil Firefox seems to work okay with it.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with `47`.

Comment: @Neil Works again by reverting back to eval...

Comment: Ah, `Number()` requires `0o` but `eval` is happy with just `0`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Neil It's good!

Comment: oh right, forgot about that :P

Answer (score 0):

## R, 84 bytes

```
function(x){s=sapply;y=s(c(8,10,16),strtoi,x=x);cat(s(y[y%in%c(32:126)],intToUtf8))}
```

uses `strtoi` to convert to each of the bases and then convert to character if in the appropriate range. Could save 4 more bytes by removing `cat` if we allowed the default printing of characters (wrapped in `""`)